# FBSession.h, iPhone, Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook

Where is "FBSession.h" in the Facebook SDK downloaded from here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk?

I've also followed the instructions from here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/213 and imported FBConnect/FBConnect.h but I can't create an instance of FBSession. Is this out of date now? The code they suggest you download can no longer be accessed from the link they give (namely http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/clients/packages/fbconnect-iphone.zip).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/). It is very easy to implement and also supports other social networks.

Comment: It is much better than trying to integrate each SDK indevidually. Less time & Less Bugs.

Comment: Did you ever encounter this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301483/iphone-twitter-and-sharing/4301550

Comment: No but I responded with what I did to enable twitter in my app.

Comment: ShareKit seems to use the Facebook iPhone SDK and not the Facebook iOS SDK. I just might try to migrate that over ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no FBSession.h on the current version of the SDK.

If you download the repo available on GitHub, under the sample folder there is a DemoApp that will give you a pretty good idea of how to implement this in your app.

Also plenty of details on how to get going on the README file https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.mdown

Answer (score 1):

> Is this out of date now?

Yes. The [old Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk) that contained the `FBSession` class is deprecated, you should use the [new one instead](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). There’s no `FBSession` any more, see the readme on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Also did you ever encounter this problem with Twitter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301483/iphone-twitter-and-sharing/4301550

Comment: No, sorry. If the server complains of bad signature, the library still uses the old authentication model, at least partially. This means that you *do* need the app secret, since that’s used to create the request signature.